# Should I buy a pi zero with my Pi 4 4GB

Tags: pi-zero-w, connection, communication

I am buying a raspberry pi 4B with 4GB of ram and I was wondering what the connectivity between raspberry pi 4 and Pi Zero is like?

Do they communicate well? and what software do you suggest?
Is there a good tutorial you can suggest?
Do you have any cool projects I can do with a pi 4 and zero?

Thanks

Comment: please do not ask for opinions .... ask a technical question instead

Comment: Ok then, Is this question better??

Comment: first question is not a question, it s a statement with a misplaced question mark ... second question, define well ... third question, software to do what ... fourth question, no ... fifth question, define cool .... you are still askng for an opinion

Comment: What sort of things do you want to do with the Pis? The easiest would just to use the built in WiFi of each and use ssh or any other TCP based comms.